# Parametric Polymorphism question in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, parametric-polymorphism

This polymorphic function allows us to flip the order of the arguments of an arbitrary curried function:

```
 # let flip f x y = f y x ;;
   val flip : ('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> 'b -> 'a -> 'c
```

That is `flip` takes a function of type 'a -> 'b -> 'c and returns a function of type b -> 'a -> 'c. But I actually don't get it, why it is correct? how the order of a,b,c are determined by ? Pretty confused about it, can anyone explain for me, thank you.

Comment: The short answer is that the order of `a` and `b` are determined by the order of `x` and `y`, and `c` is determined by the return type of `f`.

Comment: yes, I see that, but why the order is reversed, the original is x come after f, y come after x (f x y). After flipping it became f y x, but why the order of a,b,c are not mapping the same order as that ?

Comment: The return type of `f` doesn't change. So the last type variable will be the same in both cases. Only the type variables for `x` and `y` will change, because the order of the parameters is inverted.

Comment: In the other word, this is may looks silly, I'm wondering why is not ('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> ('a -> 'c -> 'b) ? I think this is make more sense to me.

Comment: As you say, the input to `flip` is a function of type `a -> b -> c`. So the type of `f` is `a -> b -> c`. The return type of `flip` is also a function. Think of what this returned function is going to return itself. It's the same as the return type of the input function. I.e., it's `c`. So your type can't be right. Your proposed type would return a type that is one of the *parameters* of `f`.

Answer (score 3):

Let's consider types of all given variables. If we have `f : 'a -> 'b -> 'c`, then from the code `f y x` in the function definition we have `y : 'a` and `x : 'b`. Also a return type of `flip` (i.e. a type of `flip f x y`) is a type of `f y x`, so `'c`.

The function `flip` has three parameters, `f`, `x`, and `y` in this order. And it returns a value of `f y x`. Therefore the type of `flip` is:

```
flip : ('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> 'b -> 'a -> 'c
       ----------------    --    --    --
         |                  |     |     |_ The type of the return value, (f y x)
         |                  |     |_ The type of y
         |                  |_ The type of x
         |_ The type of f
```

Comment: sorry, you may not answer the question I'm in, can you see my comment in last thread ? I still don't get it.

Comment: @JJE I updated my answer thoroughly. Is this clear to you? If not, could you explain steps why do you consider `flip : ('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> 'a -> 'c -> 'b`?

Comment: I actually think it's very intuitive to get answer like  ('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> 'a -> 'c -> 'b, 'a maps to f, 'b maps to x and respectively 'c to y. Because only the x and y reverse the order.

Comment: @JJE Note that `f` is a function of type `'a -> 'b -> 'c`. The type `'a` is a type of the first argument of `f`, not a type of `f` itself.

Comment: @JJE If you want more explanation, feel free to comment so :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this might help you. Instead of,

```
let flip f x y = f y x ;;
```

write the equivalent definition,

```
let flip f = fun x y -> f y x;;
```

now look at the type,

```
val flip : ('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> 'b -> 'a -> 'c
```

it's the same as this, with parenthesis,

```
val flip : ('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> ('b -> 'a -> 'c)
```

the function `flip` takes a function `f` of type `'a -> 'b -> 'c` and returns the  function `\fun x y -> f y x` of type `'b -> 'a -> 'c`.